# Can we arrange Excel CSV values in a column as List in Filter?

Tags: excel, vba

One Column consist comma separated values. Can we separate these CSV values in a list format while we use Filter.

[image]

If we click the filter drop down can we get the values in the following way

Dog
Cat
Rhino
Dog
Cat
Rat
Dog

[image]

instead of

[image]

Can we remove the comma (,) in Filter value

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is very basic data validation. `1` Select the range and give it a name. Then in Data | Data Validation, simply select "list" in "allow" and `=NameThatYouGave` in "Source"

Comment: Hi Siddharth,  I was asking in column G suppose we have CSV values please refer to the image I attached. Now we apply filter. Once we Filter we get the Filter values as CSV like the way we have in the column. Is it possible to get CSV values in list foramt in while Filtering

Comment: No you cannot get that in Autofilter as it will defeat the purpose of autofilter. However we can achieve that in Data Validation created by VBA.